# How to convert PDF to JPG using Ghostscript on Perl as I do on C#?

Tags: perl, pdf, ghostscript

I need a way to execute gswin32.exe (Ghostscript) on a Perl script as I easily do in C#, in order to convert a PDF file to a JPG file and send it somewhere. I have Googled enough and I find some Perl examples to do this but using ImageMagick. Because I'm not the one who make the decision of which technology to use, at work, on this server, I need to use GhostScript and period.

Here is how I do it on C#:

```
public static void PdfToJpg(string ghostScriptPath,string input, string output)
{
String ars = "-dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r300 -o" + output + "-%d.jpg " + input;
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = ghostScriptPath;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = ars;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
       proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.Start();
       proc.WaitForExit();
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
string ghostScriptPath = @"D:\Program Files\gs\gs9.01\bin\gswin32.exe";
string inputFileName = @"C:\test.pdf";
string outputFileName = @"E:\New\test";
PdfToJpg(ghostScriptPath, inputFileName, outputFileName);

}
```

Fine, now, can someone write a Perl example for me or at least, put me into the right direction? Please, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ghostScriptPath = 'D:\Program Files\gs\gs9.01\bin\gswin32.exe';
my $inputFileName = 'C:\test.pdf';
my $outputFileName = 'E:\New\test';
my $ars = "-dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r300 -o$outputFileName-%d.jpg $inputFileName";
system( $ghostScriptPath, $ars );
```

Comment: It almost works but Ghostscript white screen open with an error:

"dvar=name requires name=null, true, or false". In C# it works well. What could this be? :/

Comment: Escape backslashes or use single quoted strings.

Comment: I get the same error, doesn't matter if I use single quotes nor double quotes as your updated answer :/